# How can I call functions taking a System::Linq::Expressions::Expression in C++/CLI?

Tags: lambda, c++-cli

In my C++/CLI application, I'm using a library (NHibernate) that has quite a few functions that take a System::Linq::Expressions::Expression (like QueryOver's `Where()` method).

In C#, I'd be able to write:

```cs
public IEnumerable< Cat > catsByName( string name )
{
    return session.QueryOver< Cat >()
                  .Where( c => c.Name == name ) // <--- this part
                  .List< Cat >();
}
```

Obviously I can't use that syntax in C++/CLI, but I thought lambdas were just turned into anonymous delegates, and that I could set up a delegate that does the equivalent comparison and pass that to `Where()`. It doesn't work. Instead I get this compile error:

```
1>cats.cpp(54): error C2664: 'NHibernate::IQueryOver<Cat ^,Cat ^> ^NHibernate::IQueryOver<Cat ^,Cat ^>::Where(System::Linq::Expressions::Expression<System::Func<Cat ^,bool> ^> ^)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'System::Func<Cat ^,bool> ^' to 'NHibernate::Criterion::ICriterion ^'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available, or
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

How can I call these functions?

Comment: The NHibernate team counted on the friendly VB.NET or C# compiler to turn these expressions into a System::Linq::Expression automatically.  Not a feature of the C++/CLI compiler, its clock stopped ticking in 2005 and never got the Linq love.  You have to construct them yourself.  Very painful, use a disassembler as a guide.  But you most definitely want to take advantage of the famous .NET language interoperability and write these in a separate C# project that you reference in your C++/CLI project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to understand is that lambda expressions are not turned *only* into anonymous delegates. If they follow certain rules, they can also be [converted into expression trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx), which is what NHibernate's `Where()` method wants, as specified by the type of its single parameter:

```
System::Linq::Expressions::Expression< System::Func< T, bool > >
```

This is asking for an `Expression<>` instance that will resolve to a function taking a `T` and returning a `bool`, if it is compiled.

For query building, NHibernate needs expression trees so that it can translate those into equivalent SQL expressions/statements. An actual delegate is (a pointer to) a piece of executable code, which can't really be used in a SQL statement.

Any function taking an `Expression<>` wants an expression tree, probably for some expression translating or building purpose. Those functions won't take a delegate.

**But all is not lost!** If you really need to call a function taking an `Expression<>` from C++/CLI, you can! They are just objects that you can build, like anything else. Here is the translated example:

```cpp
IEnumerable< Cat ^ > ^ catsByName( String ^ name )
{
    using namespace System::Linq::Expressions;

    auto catparam = Expression::Parameter( Cat::typeid, "cat" );
    auto catname = Expression::Property( catparam, "Name" );
    auto nameconstant = Expression::Constant( name );
    auto equaltoname = Expression::Equal( catname, nameconstant );
    auto lambdaexpr = Expression::Lambda< Func< Cat ^, bool > ^ >( equaltoname, gcnew cli::array< ParameterExpression ^ >{ catparam } );

    return session->QueryOver< Cat ^ >()->Where( lambdaexpr )->List< Cat ^ >();
}
```

So you can see this is pretty ugly. You're manually building an expression tree, whereas in C#, the compiler does it for you. Also, note that one of the main benefits of using lambda expressions to build expression trees in C# is that you get compile-time type checking of properties. You won't get that in C++/CLI, because you have to fetch class properties by name, which is done with a string, at runtime.

The bottom line is that it is, indeed, possible in C++/CLI to call functions that take `Expression<>` arguments, but it's much more difficult, tedious, and error prone than in C#, and you don't really get any of the benefits. If there's any alternative, you'll probably be better off using it. Luckily, that is the case with NHibernate.